# MS-Access Chart Not Sorting Correctly

Tags: ms-access, charts

I have an MS-Access report with a chart.  I can not get the chart to sort in the order I would like it to sort.  I would like it to sort by categoryID (number) but no matter what I try, the sort order will not work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Provide sample data as text table and chart RowSource query. Is this Modern or Classic chart? Is that group/sort image from report design?

Answer (score 0):

Report Sorting and Grouping has nothing to do with graph data order.

I can only use classic MSGraph, not new Modern Charts. Consider:

In graph RowSource query, concatenate CategoryID and CategoryDescription fields:

`Format(CategoryID, "00") & " : " & CategoryDescription AS Category`

Answer (score 0):

In design view, I double clicked on the bar chart, right-clicked on the X axis area, clicked Format Axis, in the dialog box that came up, I selected Scale and selected Categories in Reverse Order.

This worked but it also put the Y axis values at the top of the graph rather than the bottom.